# can't import python goco module in python

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am getting that error while importing goco module
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74vBX.png)

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3524, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_16944/2733253088.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    import goco

  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/goco/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from goco.goco import Goco

  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/goco/goco.py", line 5, in <module>
    from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets

  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 45, in <module>
    from oauth2client import crypt

  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oauth2client/crypt.py", line 55, in <module>
    from oauth2client import _pycrypto_crypt

  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oauth2client/_pycrypto_crypt.py", line 17, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 585
    except ValueError, IndexError:
           ^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
```

Comment: where is the code that the error comes from ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: the code just import goco